# Python + NumPy - Circular shift 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

Working on an RNN using keras right now. I have successfully trained the network and I am now looking to validate / use my model. The RNN has been trained to generate 4 numbers based on an input of 15, 4 number tuples.

What I want to do is shift the 15 number vector *up* 1 so that the last row of data is nill, then substitute in the predictions made by the network at the last row. Here is where I am so far.

```
tempData = trainX[4:10]
preds = []

for i in range(5):
    # sample shape = (1,15,4)
    sample = tempData[0:1]
    # pred shape = (1,4)
    pred = model.predict(sample)
    # shift the array down so that the last row of sample = 0,0,0,0
    # then replace the null values with pred
    sample[0, len(sample) - 1] = pred[0]
    tempData[0] = sample[0]
    preds.append(pred)
```

Here, im taking a sub sample of the training data and simply using the first set of 15 numbers as the basis for the predictions. There is no shifting taking place but from my understanding the prediction should at least be over-writing the last row of the data, however this is not working at the moment.